# How do I install Catalyst drivers for ATI Mobillity Radeon X1400 in 12.04?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I'm trying to install drivers in Ubuntu 12.04 for my ATI Mobility Radeon X1400 and haven't worked out how to yet. I'm not new to Ubuntu but now that I want to play TF2 on it I need Catalyst. Can someone please tell me how to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the dash.
2. Search "Software Sources", open the app.
3. Go to the Additional Drivers tab

There, you can check for Catalyst drivers and install them automatically.

As a last resort if this does not work, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI for instructions on how to use the terminal to do it. Or post back with any problems you may have. Everything should go fine, though. The Additional Driver (jockey) program is the bee's knees.